# Satellite emitting x-rays?

Tags: satellite, x-ray

On the local TV news, it was alleged that x-rays from some satellite could interfere with something on earth.  I didn't hear it but my wife thought they were talking about WiFi or internet or something like that.  (She's had people jobs, so technical details aren't her expertise.)

I know that more than one satellite is **detecting** x-rays.  Are there actually any emitting them?  If so, what could it interfere with?  (Perhaps the latter question belongs on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com).)

Comment: Please link to this news item.  This question is a question about the operation of an artificial satellite, and so is off topic here.  But it may be on topic at [space.se].  But you will need the link to the news item to be in place.

Comment: X-rays can’t penetrate the Earth’s atmosphere, so the scenario as stated isn’t possible. (And I don’t see how even locally generated X-rays could interfere with WiFi.)

Comment: Me neither.  But I am still skeptical about whether a satellite emitting x-rays even exists.

Comment: There is some interest in looking at X-ray communications with deep space spacecraft, but in this case the transmissions would be pointed *away* from Earth and towards some distant spacecraft. See Space Exploration SE questions tagged [x-ray-communication](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-communication) especially [What will the X-ray communications (XCOM) transmitter look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19881/12102)